# Процедуры mysql, когда, да, а когда, нет

Tags: mysql, innodb

Возник вопрос, в каких ситуациях имеет смысл, использовать хранимые процедуры. В данный момент процедуры я использую, только если сталкиваюсь с ситуациями, когда нужно производить, n кол-во внесений с получением id, и полученные id вносить в какую то общую таблицу, условно (псевдокод):

```
ip          = get_ip; 
fingerprint = get_fing();
user_agent  = get_ua();
timestamp   = get_time();

insert list_ua set user_agent on duplicate update id = last_insert_id(id);
ua_id = last_insert_id();

insert fingerprint set fingerprint on duplicate update id = last_insert_id(id);
fingerprint_id = last_insert_id();

insert ip set ip on duplicate update id = last_insert_id(id);
ip_id = last_insert_id();

insert track set ua_id, fingerprint_id, ip_id, timestamp;
```

Comment: Когда да, тогда да))) А вообще, если нужна цепочка большая из запросов, то можно процедурами обработать. С данными пользователя тоже удобнее через процедуры (и безопаснее).

Comment: *в каких ситуациях имеет смысл использовать хранимые процедуры.* Когда надо запретить прямой доступ к данным. Когда надо выполнить блок кода из нескольких запросов, особенно если он итерационный. Когда блок кода содержит динамический SQL. Ситуаций на самом деле много...